# NodeJS Usage require('../');

Tags: node.js

I am in the process of learning NodeJs and stumbled across this line of code:

```
var irsdk = require('../');
```

I cannot figure out what is being loaded. I can see where the variable is being used and calling functions.

I understand how to use the require statement when loading a particular file.

If anyone could shed some light it would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The module that's being loaded is an `index.js` file one level up from where you currently are.

Comment: ok great, that makes sense, but it threw me off, because it did not specify it.  Does it know to call that file by convention, or is it because it is listed as the main in the package.json file?

Comment: It's how Nodes module loader works, @zzzzBovs answer shows how the modules are looked up.

Answer (score 4):

From [Node's documentation on Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together)

> ```
> require(X) from module at path Y
> 1. If X is a core module,
>    a. return the core module
>    b. STOP
> 2. If X begins with './' or '/' or '../'
>    a. LOAD_AS_FILE(Y + X)
>    b. LOAD_AS_DIRECTORY(Y + X)
> 3. LOAD_NODE_MODULES(X, dirname(Y))
> 4. THROW "not found"
>
> LOAD_AS_FILE(X)
> 1. If X is a file, load X as JavaScript text.  STOP
> 2. If X.js is a file, load X.js as JavaScript text.  STOP
> 3. If X.json is a file, parse X.json to a JavaScript Object.  STOP
> 4. If X.node is a file, load X.node as binary addon.  STOP
>
> LOAD_AS_DIRECTORY(X)
> 1. If X/package.json is a file,
>    a. Parse X/package.json, and look for "main" field.
>    b. let M = X + (json main field)
>    c. LOAD_AS_FILE(M)
> 2. If X/index.js is a file, load X/index.js as JavaScript text.  STOP
> 3. If X/index.json is a file, parse X/index.json to a JavaScript object. STOP
> 4. If X/index.node is a file, load X/index.node as binary addon.  STOP
>
> LOAD_NODE_MODULES(X, START)
> 1. let DIRS=NODE_MODULES_PATHS(START)
> 2. for each DIR in DIRS:
>    a. LOAD_AS_FILE(DIR/X)
>    b. LOAD_AS_DIRECTORY(DIR/X)
>
> NODE_MODULES_PATHS(START)
> 1. let PARTS = path split(START)
> 2. let I = count of PARTS - 1
> 3. let DIRS = []
> 4. while I >= 0,
>    a. if PARTS[I] = "node_modules" CONTINUE
>    c. DIR = path join(PARTS[0 .. I] + "node_modules")
>    b. DIRS = DIRS + DIR
>    c. let I = I - 1
> 5. return DIRS
> ```

`require('../')` runs the `LOAD_AS_DIRECTORY(X)` section for the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

To make this simple, just keep in mind that if you dont specify a file but a directory, it will be the `index.js` file that will be loaded.

In the current case, we are requiring `../` witch will load the index of the upper directory.

Answer (score -1):

It could be the InRule SDK for JS (http://www.inrule.com/products/inrule-for-javascript/) Which can be used to separate your business logic out from your application logic.

Or, it could be the npm 'node-irsdk' package which appears to be a telemetry package of some sort that enhances the existing "utils" module. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-irsdk)

Either way, you can log it out to the console to get more information about it by literally logging the variable.

```
console.log(irsdk);
//or
console.dir(irsdk);
//both must be called AFTER you instantiate the var irsdk = req.....
```